# Preserving GString newlines and whitespace in HTML-Output

Tags: grails, groovy

So I've been using GStrings to generate SQL onto the users screen, however this causes everything to be one continuous line. Is it possible with GStrings to insert a new line or even put more space between characters?

As you can see below I've tried "\n" aswell as '\n' without success.

GString example below

```
def result = 
        """

    mlp_template_cp.template_ins (in_template_name => ${toStringOrNull(template.name)} "\n"
    ,in_description  => ${toStringOrNull(template.description)} "\n"
    , in_progression_type  => ${toStringOrNull(template.progressionType)} "\n"
    , in_default_plan_type => ${toStringOrNull(template.defaultPlanType)} "\n"
    , in_default_plan_phase => ${toStringOrNull(template.defaultPlanPhase)} "\n"
    , in_gui_flag => ${toStringOrNull(template.guiFlag)} "\n"
    , in_ext_fun => ${toStringOrNull(template.extFun)} "\n"
    ,out_tmpl_sysid => v_mt_sysid); "\n"

        """
```

Comment: how do you detect this problem?  what do you mean by userscreen (console, browser, ...)?  GStrings honour linebreaks (no "\n" needed).

Comment: I print this GString to the browser but as I said I can't get linebreaks to work. Any spaces or linebreaks I put in by keypresses just act as one space.

Comment: when you render html, then whitespaces are ignored by default in the browser.  put your output in a `<pre>`-tag.

Comment: This is a groovy grails application so where would I put the <pre> tags?

Comment: the place, where you output your result (your gsp most likely)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers ignore multiple whitespaces and `\n` line breaks. You have to use `&nbsp;` and `<br />` instead:

```
def result = 
        """
    <br /><br />
    mlp_template_cp.template_ins (in_template_name => ${toStringOrNull(template.name)} <br />
    ,in_description &nbsp;=> ${toStringOrNull(template.description)} <br />
    , in_progression_type &nbsp;=> ${toStringOrNull(template.progressionType)} <br />
    , in_default_plan_type => ${toStringOrNull(template.defaultPlanType)} <br />
    , in_default_plan_phase => ${toStringOrNull(template.defaultPlanPhase)} <br />
    , in_gui_flag => ${toStringOrNull(template.guiFlag)} <br />
    , in_ext_fun => ${toStringOrNull(template.extFun)} <br />
    ,out_tmpl_sysid => v_mt_sysid); <br />
    <br />
        """
```

Note that you also have to escape certain characters for html (like `<`, `>`, `&`, ..). The easiest way to do this is to use a third party library like `commons-lang` [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29)